# Gradient of the normal to the curve confusion

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The equation of a curve is $y=e^{\frac{1}{2} x +1} $ find the gradient of the normal of the curve at the point where x= 0

My trial -

$y' = \frac{1}{2} e^{\frac{1}{2} x +1} $

When $x=0$

$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{2} e $

here comes my conceptual problem .

The gradient of the normal to the curve .

From what I understand-

Let's say a straight line graph with $m=5$ , the gradient of the normal which is like the perpendicular bisector of the gradient is $m=-5$

So linking it to the question gradient of the curve ,

Why is it

$\frac{-2}{e} $ instead of $\frac{-1}{2} e $

Comment: You are wrong. If $m$ is the slope of some line, a perpendicular line has slope $-1/m$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the normal line and the tangent line to a curve at one given point on the curve are **perpendicular** to each other, and thus the product of their slopes is $\;-1\;$, and this means

$$\text{Slope of the tangent line is}\;\;\frac e2\;\;\iff\;\text{ the slope of the normai line is}\;\;-\frac1{\frac e2}=-\frac2e$$